# 関数テンプレートにメンバ関数ポインタを渡したときに"No matching function for call to '*'"が発生する

Tags: c++

言語: C++
C++: 17
IDE: Qt Creator 10.0.1
Qt: 6.4.3
コンパイラ: MSVC 2019, x86_64

いくつかのgetter/setterが定義されたクラスがあります。

```
class detect_gravity {
private:
    cv::Point2i _gravity_point;
    cv::Point2i _decimation;
    int32_t _level;

public:
    const cv::Point2i &gravity_point() const { return _gravity_point; }
    const cv::Point2i &decimation() const { return _decimation; }
    void decimation(const cv::Point2i &value) { _decimation = value; }
    int32_t level() { return _level; }
    void level(const int32_t &value) { _level = value; }
};
```

このようなクラスが複数種類あり、プロパティの型も様々です。
これらのgetter/setterをすべて同じ型にして変数に格納したいと考えています。

例えば、
getterは`std::function<const void*(void*)>`の形で
戻り値は取得した値へのポインタ、引数はプロパティを持つクラスのインスタンスへのポインタ。
(ここでは'detect_gravity'クラスのインスタンス)

setterは`std::function<void(void*, const void*)>`の形で、
第1引数はクラスインスタンスへのポインタ、第2引数は設定する値へのポインタ。

そして、それらをプロパティの管理クラスへ登録します。
登録時は以下の様に書きます。(decimationプロパティの場合)

```
config.register_property(
    "プロパティ名", "プロパティの説明",
    make_getter<const cv::Point2i &() const>(&detect_gravity::decimation),
    make_setter<void(const cv::Point2i&)>(&detect_gravity::decimation));
```

make_getterおよびmake_setterは下記の通りです。

```
template <class _Rx, class _Ty>
proc_system::getter_t make_getter(_Rx _Ty::*getter) {
    return [getter](void *obj) -> const void* {
        _Ty *pobj = static_cast<_Ty*>(obj);
        auto &val = (pobj->*getter)();
        return static_cast<const void*>(&val);
    };
}

template <class _Rx, class _Ty, class _Arg>
proc_system::setter_t make_setter(_Rx (_Ty::*setter)()) {
    return [setter](void* obj, const void* val){
        auto pobj = static_cast<_Ty*>(obj);
        auto pval = static_cast<_Arg*>(val);
        (pobj->*setter)(*pval);
    };
}
```

このとき、`make_setter<void(const cv::Point2i&)>(&detect_gravity::decimation)`の部分で

```
エラー: No matching function for call to 'make_setter'
```

と出てしまいます。
また、make_setter内では以下のエラーが出ています。

```
Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Rx = void (const cv::Point2i &)]:
function cannot return function type 'void (const cv::Point2i &)' (aka 'void (const Point_<int> &)')
```

上記のエラーはなぜ起こっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make_setter` の引数の型が，「引数無し」のメンバ関数になっていたりとか，いろいろと問題がありますね．

当該引数が参照である場合，「参照のポインタ」はダメなので，そこも対処する必要がありそうです．

`make_setter` template を使う箇所の文法も明らかに間違っています．

```
using setter_t = std::function<void(void*, const void*)>;

//こんなのでとりあえずいけるかも？
template < class Rx, class Ty, class Arg >
setter_t make_setter( Rx (Ty::*setter)(Arg) ) {  //←引数が要るよね
    return [setter](void* obj, const void* val){
        auto pobj = static_cast<Ty*>(obj);
        auto pval = static_cast< std::remove_reference_t<Arg> * >(val);  //←Argが参照だったらどうするのか，というのが要る
        (pobj->*setter)(*pval);  //←ココ，Rx は常に捨てる？
    };
}

//使う側：template型引数というのはこのように指定するのでは
make_setter<void,detect_gravity,const cv::Point2i&>(&detect_gravity::decimation);
```

＃関係ないけど，こういうのをどこぞに登録できたとして，どうやって正しく使うんだろう？

Comment: make_getter の方に関しては，実際のgetterの戻り値型次第では一時オブジェクトへのポインタを返す形になってしまってダメな気がしますが，どうなんでしょう．

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。templateの使い方についてですが、std::mem_fnを使う場合、`auto f1 = std::mem_fn<const cv::Point2i&, detect_gravity>(&detect_gravity::decimation);`とするとオーバーロードがあった場合にコンパイルエラーになりますが`auto f2 = std::mem_fn<const cv::Point2i &() const>(&detect_gravity::decimation);`とするとオーバーロードが正しく認識されたので、それと同じようにした次第です。なぜそれで上手くいくのかは勉強中なのですが…

Comment: 個人的に「登録できたとして，どうやって正しく使うんだろう？」に興味があるのですが，全部 `void*` に見える側からどうやって使う想定なのでしょうか？

Comment: 使ったことないので詳細を知りませんが，`std::any` とかいうのを使うと `void*` よりも良いことがあるのかもしれません．（今現在，問答無用の `static_cast` になっている個所で何らかの型チェックができるようになる？）

Comment: ここでは省略しましたが、プロパティの登録時に型も登録します。例えば、その型を見ながら値を表示させるのに適したViewへgetterを注入したいと考えています。各View側では自分が表示する型は分かっているので適宜キャストして値を表示できるかと思っています。